# MySQL count registered users joined across multiple tables

Tags: mysql

There are 3 tables needed to create this report.  Two are tables with the data, and the 3rd table is one used in previous steps to gather the report data.

Table 1.  Users.

```
us_usid (int)
us_user (varchar) default empty string
```

Table 2. UserGroups

```
ug_usid (int) = users.us_usid
ug_group (varchar 6) = group id
```

Table 3. Report

```
re_group (varchar 6) = usergroups.ug_group
re_registered_count (int) = count of users with username
```

Must simplifed schema, but shows the columns involved.  The report table has around 500 group IDs in them.  I need to count the users whose us_user <> '' and whos us_usid is in the ug_usid grouped by the ug_group IDs in the report table.

For example, the report table has '533103' as a group ID.  The UserGroups table has 545 users who have that ug_group.  Those ug_usids correspond to 545 users in the users table of which 373 have a value for the us_user string.  I need to get that "373" number into the report table.

If figured out how to pull all of the other necessary data but cannot find a working (and efficient way- these are groups with between 1000 and 100000 members) method to figure out how many are registered in one fell swoop.

Comment: A little data (for each table) would make a huge difference. Then, also, the result you would expect from that sample. Together that is the best way to convey your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Count of users per user group, where there is a value in us_user

```
select ug.us_user, count(u.us_usid)
from UserGroups ug
inner join Usersu on ug.ug_usid = u.us_usid
where u.us_user IS NOT NULL
```